# Best method to determine if viewport or 'standard' browser

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, cross-browser

So, by now we all know that iOS mobile Safari uses viewports (as does Android browser), rather than a 'standard' browser window. And this causes issues with `overflow:hidden`, and `position:fixed`.

This unfortunately is the same case with the iPad. I presume this is the case for other Android tablets too.

Rather than browser sniffing each time, is there an easy way to determine if the browser has a viewport or if it is standard?

Comment: Just to confirm, media queries is not the solution unfortunately :(

Comment: i.e. a laptop with 1024 x 768 vs an iPad with 1024 x 768.... laptop will be fine, not a viewport, but iPad has a viewport

Comment: It looks like you might misunderstand what a "viewport" is.  **Every** browser has a *viewport*, not just those on mobile devices.  The [viewport](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html) is defined as the part of the browser window where your page is rendered.  Also, while [some mobile browsers do render `position:fixed` incorrectly](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html), not all do.  And, `overflow` has issues with `auto` and `scroll`, but not `hidden`.  Bottom line: elaborate more on what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Oh sorry, Josh... is is just a case of the mobile broswers not rendering it correctly, as in a bug? or as in chosen?

Comment: Basically... I am browser sniffing, to determine if the browser is ipad, to run some js to force the position fixed using js. But I dont really want to use browser sniffing, as it is the same for android webkit too. I was presuming *these* browsers have some kind of property or variable to determine whether they have the *funky* viewport

Comment: I understand that all browsers have a viewport, but I presumed due to the way these devices render position fixed, and a few other things, was down to their viewport type. Any help would be greatly received :) I am still using the term viewport as I have no better word to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's currently no good fix for mobile browsers' lack of support for `position:fixed`.  The reason `position:fixed` is "broken" in the first place is because—among other things—no browser vendor knows exactly how to handle what happens when zooming in on the document.  If you have some time to do some reading, I highly recommend the following articles, which will explain browser viewports and the problems surrounding `fixed` positioning on mobile in great, painstaking detail:

- [A tale of two viewports – part two](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html) — how viewports work and the problem of mobile browsers.  (If you're not familiar with viewports in desktop browsers or want the background info, see also [part one](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html).)
- [The fifth position value](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/12/the_fifth_posit.html) does a fantastic job of explaining the problems surrounding `position:fixed` in a mobile browser, and suggests we might need a new `position` value – `device-fixed`.

Those articles will give you the *why*, but not the *how to fix it*.  For a truly `fixed` position, you're mostly out of luck.  However, if your goal is to have a fixed toolbar below scrolling content, there are [a few ways](http://www.google.com/search?q=position+fixed+mobile) to hack it.  I've had success with [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4).

---

**Edit:** The correct way to determine if you are running on a touch-based device is the following feature detection:

```
var isTouch = ('ontouchstart' in window);
```

`ontouchstart` is an event fired in [mobile Safari and the Android browser](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableTouch.html).  It is not present on desktop browsers, where you can just use `overflow:auto` and have regular scrollbars.  If `isTouch` is true, you can then use iScroll.

Comment: Hey Josh, thanks, yeah I guess that is kinda as expected... I am using iscroll for ipad, by browser sniffing, but was hoping there was a cleaner fix, with more and more tablets coming out.... :(

Comment: @sydlawrence: I've added some feature detection code I've used before.  This should be a little more future-proof.

Answer (score -1):

Try media queries: you can include stylesheets, or apply parts of a stylesheet conditionally, based on the device and viewport dimensions the browser reports.

This article gives a decent enough introduction: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: media queries is not what I want, i.e. a laptop with 1024 x 768 vs an iPad with 1024 x 768....