# Detect if browser care about meta viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, viewport

I want to accomplish something, and for that I need to know if the browser care about the meta viewport.

For example, chrome for iOS will be adjusted by the content of viewport. But chrome for windows won't.

What would be the best way to know if a browser uses the viewport content?

Comment: While there may be ways to do that, it seems that you have split your original problems into two parts: an easy one and an impossible one.

It might be helpful if you included your original problem in the question as well.

Comment: It might be best to go with feature detection, i.e. "var isTouch = ('ontouchstart' in window);" as per this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636774/best-method-to-determine-if-viewport-or-standard-browser

Comment: Some visitors in my site don't care about responsive design and prefer to use the "full" design. There are few ways to turn the responsive off, I found that what works the best for me is manipulating the viewport data. But I need to know if the browser supports it, so if it's not I could provide some kind of fallback.

Comment: This is a legit question and heuristics like checking if touch is enabled won't cut it - for all we know desktop browsers will start responding to the viewport tag at some point.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like setting the `viewport` tag is up for a bit of [debate](http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho). It sounds like your question might warrant ("Some visitors in my site don't care about responsive design") looking into the afore-tagged **HTMLBOY** blogpost; however, if you continue to use it, there are a few things to be aware of (the first, second, and third really being the take away points):

1. The website, itself, must be responsive - not just the browser, i.e. `<meta... content="width=device-width">` won't do anything unless your website knows how to scale
2. It is [true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) that the `viewport` tag is not currently a part of any web standard and was originally Apple-proprietary (this is the root, perhaps, of your problem). [Not all browsers support it.](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/)
3. [A pixel is not a pixel](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html), i.e. a CSS pixel is not a physical pixel - the two are not tied together (this means that configuration attributes on the `<meta>` tag when related to the `viewport` can become problematic (particularly considering point no. 2, above, and elucidated in the linked MDN article in the same point). For further reading about the complications, you can read [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html) and [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972)
4. (helpful tip) If content on the website is important, don't set the `maximum-scale` or the `user-scalable=no` attributes. This will stop the user from examining important text more closely.

**Now that all that is out of the way...**

The answer to your question, "What would be the best way to know if a browser uses the viewport content?", is that there really is no great way to do it.

However, we do have two properties that can help us using in-line JavaScript that relate to the two concepts of the "visual viewport" (smaller) and the "layout viewport"  (wider) thanks to the incompatibility between browsers "back in the day".

The *visual viewport* is the part the users sees on his or her screen - the part currently seen. This is what is scrolled when examining content larger than the device screen.

Everything related to CSS is calculated in relation to the *layout viewport*. As the linked article states, "How wide is the layout viewport? That differs from browser to browser."

> Thus the  element takes the width of the layout viewport
>   initially, and your CSS is interpreted as if the screen were
>   significantly wider than the phone screen. This makes sure that your
>   site’s layout behaves as it does on a desktop browser.

So, how can we leverage this to our advantage?

We can't detect if the browser *supports* the tag; however, we can detect if the browser has applied it. I'm not going to re-invent the wheel, so I'll link you to this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23708819/3469725) and then an [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html) which (already linked above) delves deeply into the topic. This knowledge should point you in the right direction.